# Is there any ways we can update talend patch from Talend Studio?

Tags: ide, talend, patch, nexus3

I am using Nexus repository for new updates of talend and i have new updates But i dont think that updates are getting reflected in my Talend Studio 7.1

I am facing Certificate expiration issue which is resolved in talend patch and i have that patch too just i cannot reflect that into studio.

I Know the way where we create patches folder in talend directory but it is also not working for some reason but is there any way i can do this manually in studio.

Comment: are you sure that your patch is for the studio ? sometimes patches are for TAC/TMC only.

Comment: yes i am sure, actually i am having issue with building job and it is resolved in Patch_20201211_TPS-4416_v2